# What does Ding do?

Tags: baldurs-gate-2-enhanced

What's the point of Dings? I received the cat after finding 8 cats for Barad Ding in the Wild Mage Encampment. Does he have a use or is it just one of those strange items that Baldur's Gate gives you from time to time?

[image: Dings the cat]